# Handling configuration changes with MVVM android

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, screen-orientation, android-jetpack

Hello I'm using MVVM architecture (ViewModel, LiveData) to develop my android app and I have one activity and 2 fragments in it , when I'm in second fragment and rotate the screen the second fragment is detached and destroyed and home screen is displayed, How can I handle this configuration change in MVVM? Will Navigation Component solve this problem? Or do I have to follow traditional way of handling Configuration changes?

Comment: Android Navigation component would work in this case. Please try before asking.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thank you for the response, Sure I was about to try Navigation Component just making sure :)

Comment: No worries. If there are any issues. Post the issues here.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Sure, Thank you so much :)